# HTTP Request with Certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate

how can i hit a url with using certificate, can not throw exception. must have to include certificate. suggest me some demo example. I am able to read the certificate but how can i hit a url using this certificate..

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;


public class httpcert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileInputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream("/home/devel-p/Android/PKI/CA.crt");
            CertificateFactory x509CertFact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)x509CertFact.generateCertificate(is);
            System.out.println(cert);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL connection only sends the client certificate if the server asks for it, and the certificate is only mandatory if the server so decides. You can't control any of that from the client end.

Comment: yes it is mandatory..server needs client certificate..how can i add it

Comment: Just make it available in your keystore, along with the keypair it was generated from, and set the system properties `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` appropriately. You now seem to be asking a completely different question.